Is there a way to use openssl cms with a symmetric key without exposing the key on the command line?
I use openssl cms to encrypt and sign files sent to embedded Linux devices. I use PKI for the verification step and a symmetric key for the decryption step. It recently occurred to me that when openssl cms -binary -decrypt -secretkey <key in hex> -secretkeyid 0 -inform DER -in <input file> -out <output file> is called on the embedded device, the secret key is exposed to anyone logged in to the system. E.g., if anyone is monitoring top, they'll see the key as a command line argument. I don't mind if root users can see this key, but I don't want non-root users to see it.
Some ways around this I've thought of:

Patch openssl cms to support another way to supply the key.
Write a C program that uses openssl libcrypto functions.
Stop using a symmetric key; add another PKI pair for this decryption.

I don't want to do #3 because it will break existing compatibility.
Is there another way I can accomplish what I am after?

OpenSSL (nee SSLeay) was designed primarily to be a library callable from user code, and the commandline executable was created as a test tool with often limited and even perverse functionality. If you were starting out I'd say use GPG which was designed for interactive use and has much better key management, and is almost equally free/open and widely available and used on Linux, but it's rather too late for that.

We started with GPG a few years ago for a similar purpose. We pivoted to using OpenSSL and CMS files because it allowed us to standardize our set of tools a bit for some other purposes. I agree with you; GPG was purpose-built for exactly what we're trying to do. Using OpenSSL CMS isn't the obvious first choice for file encryption and signing.

Thank you for this history of the OpenSSL command line interface. I wasn't aware of that. That will be good to keep in mind for the future.

I'd say option 2 is pretty tempting – especially since the openssl binary already exists and shows you how to do that. If you're a bit lazy, and you'd be right to be, you can run your openssl command with all options through ltrace to see what gets called in which order, then check that against the documentation of these functions.

You don't need to trace or debug; OpenSSL is open source and has been for 30 years (effectively).

@dave_thompson_085 absolutely, but have you tried to read the source code of the openssl command?

I've read quite a few chunks of the OpenSSL package, of which the commandline is only about 5%, and while much of it isn't well commented, it does show the structure and have variable names and true data types, all of which are missing from a trace or a debug without symbols, and to debug with symbols you need to recompile anyway.

If your embedded device allows it, you can compile a small shim to pre-load the openssl binary with some code to manipulate the args passed to the program, for example to replace one argument value by another copied from the environment.  The environment is not visible to other users in ps. Compile this C code:
/* https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/785591/119298
 * gcc -Wall -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o shim_main.so shim_main.c
 * LD_PRELOAD=shim_main.so SECRETKEY=abc openssl ... XXX ...
 */
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed to get RTLD_NEXT defined in dlfcn.h */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef int (*pfi)(int, char **, char **);
static pfi real_main;

/* copy argv to new location, replace magic string by secrret from env */
char **copyargs(int argc, char** argv){
    char *secretkey;
    char **newargv;

    secretkey = getenv("SECRETKEY");
    if(secretkey==0)return argv;
    newargv = malloc((argc+1)*sizeof(*argv));
    for(int i = 0; i<argc; i++){
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "XXX")==0)
            newargv[i] = secretkey;
        else newargv[i] = argv[i];
    }
    newargv[argc] = 0;
    return newargv;
}
static int mymain(int argc, char** argv, char** env){
    // fprintf(stderr, "main argc %d\n", argc);
    return real_main(argc, copyargs(argc,argv), env);
}

int __libc_start_main(pfi main, int argc,
                      char **ubp_av, void (*init) (void),
                      void (*fini)(void),
                      void (*rtld_fini)(void), void (*stack_end)){
    static int (*real___libc_start_main)() = NULL;

    if (!real___libc_start_main) {
        char *error;
        real___libc_start_main = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "__libc_start_main");
        if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
            // fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    real_main = main;
    return real___libc_start_main(mymain, argc, ubp_av, init, fini,
            rtld_fini, stack_end);
}

You cannot interpose the function main() as such, so we hook our shim on
__libc_start_main(). Compile as given in the C comment, and run with
LD_PRELOAD=shim_main.so SECRETKEY=realsecret openssl ... XXX ...

Of course, instead of getting the secretkey from the
environment we could read it from a file or open file descriptor and so on.
Beware, this hook is very early in the startup so it must stay simple.

What if you store the key in a file with restricted permission to only root user by placing the symmetric key in a file and set its permissions so that only root can read it
1. echo -n "your_symmetric_key_here" > /path/to/keyfile.bin
2. chmod 600 /path/to/keyfile.bin

you can then use a subshell to read the contents securely without passing the key directly as a command-line argument.
openssl cms -encrypt -aes-256-cbc -in plaintext.txt -out encrypted.txt -inkey /path/to/keyfile.bin


cms -inkey is used only for asymmetric private key for signing or decryption, not for symmetric encryption (or decryption). If by 'subshell' you meant command substitution i.e. openssl cms ... -secret_key $(cat /path/to/keyfile) ... that doesn't hide the value from ps/top/etc, although it does exclude it from shell history if this is done interactively which it probably isn't. (And a symmetric key is hex so calling it .bin is misleading.)

The man page confused me at first. I also initially thought I could use -inkey to specify a symmetric key. Alas, that's not how it works, even though it seems to be how it should work.

Oh noted, mixed it up
